# "Power-counting renormalizable theory" which is non-renormalizable

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

This question can probably be reduced to semantics and I have read the similar ones already asked.

On page 27 of the volume 2 of his series on QFT, Weinberg states:

> ...there is more to renormalizability than power counting; it is
> necessary also that there be a counterterm to absorb every divergence.

In my understanding, if a theory is power counting renormalizable -- in the sense that if every term in the lagrangian is of dimension 4 or less in 4D spacetime -- then a finite number of counterterms is enough to cure the divergences to each order in perturbation theory and the theory is renormalizable.

**(1)** If this is correct what does Weinberg mean by the statement?

**(2)** I assume that what he meant is related to the following confusion to which I have received contradictory answers: if a theory can indeed be rendered finite (in perturbation theory) but for that we need to add terms whose form was not in the original lagrangian, is the theory renormalizable? Is it useful/physical? What would be an example of something like that?

Comment: Profs theory (massive maxwell) is one possible example